# How to search restaurants which are in New York City?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a web crawler and the whole web to crawl.
what should be my strategy? what kind of classification algorithms should i use ?

I am saying i have a web crawler , i din mean manually crawling the web .

Comment: Umm... manually filling in the data?

Comment: Cheapest and best would be buying an Restaurant Guide (No joke!) But you might get problemw with copyright. So also consider if the is an authority which provides that data.

Comment: ok then why do you ask people to use Google ? rather buy a relevent text rather then searching over google. My question is i have a web crawler , how to use that crawler to classify relevant text for me , just open ideas i am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and classify each page you crawl and determine if it is a restaurant or not (binary classifier) and use **[supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning)**.

You can use the **[Bag of Words model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model)** for it - which means, use the words as "features" and their existence (and number of occurances) determines the value of the feature.

You will also need to first manually label a set of pages and determine for them if they are a restaurant page or not. The data you generate is called your *training set*.

Note that the bag of words model tend to have a huge feature space - so you are going to need a classifier that is not sensitive to non informative features.

You can later use **[cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29)** to estimate how good your model is.

Here are some suggestions I found useful when classifying data using the bag of words model:

- **[SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)** tends to be very useful and yield very good results for the Bag of Words model. I did not see significance different between the performance of linear kernel and gaussian kernel.
- Use [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and filter [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) - you don't need the noise it generates.
- Use [bi-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram), they are very informative and at least for me - tend to increase the accuracy of the classifier significantly.